# Navigation back to main view

Tags: iphone

I have a root view controller as the navigation controller. In the root view controller nib file I have 3 buttons (button 1, button 2, button3). Each of which has a table view contoller Eg: Flow of the buttons (I have followed the navigation logic such that at any time I can get back to the root view controller by selecting the back button).

On Button 1 click => table view shown ==>  detail view shown on item click/selection

On Button 2 click => table view shown ==>  detail view shown on item click/selection

This logic holds good for all the buttons. In the detail view I have a button.

What I want is on the click of this button, the button 3 logic should be called such that, when i click or press the back button from the table view of 3rd button, I should get back to the main root view controller with all the buttons visible.

Please let me know how should i go ahead with the same.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you want. Could you elaborate it?

Comment: hi, i have 3 buttons. On the click of these buttons a table view is being shown. And on the selection of any item from the table view, all i am doing is creating a view with the details of the selected item. IN addition, I have a button in this view. On the selection/press of thsi button, all I want is to call the some other table view controller. Except to the fact that I want to clear the previous stack of navigation objects, such that when I click back on the navigation bar, i am redirected to the root view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll want to use the `- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` found in `UINavigationController`. As the name suggests, this will allow you to pop back to the root view controller at any time.